# Create a mouse left click event when user scrolls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make a c# win forms app that will do a left mouse click event whenever the user scrolls even when outside of the application. I am using a thread and have the constants needed but I do not know how to check if the user scrolls, simulate mouse click.
I have this for using the mouse events and created a thread.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

        private const int LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        private const int LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        private const int RIGHTUP = 0x00010;
        private const int RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
        private const int WHEEL = 0x0800;
        public int debounceTime = 8;
```

What would I have to write in the thread for it to check if there is a scroll wheel event, and then send a mouse left event?

Comment: [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) + [`EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants) to `EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND`.